# Change iframe src by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an `iframe` that looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" height=1000 width="500" id="myiframe"></iframe>
```

I want to create a link so that when I click on it, the iframe on the page changes. How can I do that using jQuery? Is it related to jQuery `attr`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that. You don't even need JavaScript for that.

Give your iframe a `name`, and target your anchors to point to it:

```
<a href="foo.html" target="myiframe">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.html" target="myiframe">Bar</a>
<a href="baz.html" target="myiframe">Baz</a>

<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

This degrades nicely for people who have JavaScript turned off.

Answer (score 0):

on clicking in the link "click here" // it will take move the link to the iframe as specified....

```
<a href="cart.html" target="test" onclick="document.getElementById('test').frameBorder=1"> Click Here </a>
<iframe src="blank.html" frameborder="0" name="test" id="test" width=1200 height=800></iframe>
```