# How to apply pagination in IFrame

Tags: html, xhtml

I have an IFrame with a Table enclosed within it. I want to display 15 rows of a table and than a Next button must be there to move forward.

How to apply pagination for IFrame?

Comment: Do you want the 'next page' and 'prev page' links in the IFrame or in the main page? If you want it inside the IFrame you just construct your page with the correct pagination within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially answered in [Basic jQuery question: How to change iframe src by clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473295/basic-jquery-question-how-to-change-iframe-src-by-clicking-a-link).

You would just need to build GET parameters for the frame source, and build links for each of the values in the main page.

For example:

```
<a href="foo.html?page=1" target="myiframe">Page 1</a>
<a href="foo.html?page=2" target="myiframe">Page 2</a>
<a href="foo.html?page=3" target="myiframe">Page 3</a>

<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

The catch is that your main page will need to know the status of the frame to generate the right links -- this will require some javascript parsing of the frame source URL and regenerating the links based on that.

Instead of using a frame, I would recommend loading the whole table inside the main page and using something like [DataTables](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html) to generate the pagination for you.