# Making a link to change src on iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascript/jquery code in PHP:

```
$theframe='thisbox';
echo "<a href='#' onClick=\"\$('#$theframe').attr('src','http://google.com';\">
<span class='lin'>$titlehere</span></a>";
```

When clicked, I want it to update the iframe on the page with id='theframe' to something else (like google here) and without refreshing the page.

It's not working.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  For future reference, here is what I've used.

```
<a href="foo.html" target="myiframe">Foo</a>
<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

From:
[Basic jQuery question: How to change iframe src by clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473295/basic-jquery-question-how-to-change-iframe-src-by-clicking-a-link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the frame a name, then use the target attribute, forget JS.

```
<a href="http://example.net/" target="myFrame">Example</a>

<iframe name="myFrame" src="http://example.com/">
    Alternative content for non-frame systems
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new div and set its "innerHTML" value by each click. The innerHTML value then contains a new iframe with its source.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent the link's default behaviour with `event.preventDefault()`.
I'd also split html and javascript:

PHP:

```
echo "<a href='#' id='someID'><span class='lin'>$titlehere</span></a>";
```

JS:

```
$('#someID').click(function(ev){
    $('#theframe').attr('src','http://google.com');
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```