# How to open iframe in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, iframe, wordpress

I want to open a php page of my wordpress plugin in iframe ?  In this page i wants that that my form will be displayed with header and footer of wordpres. If you have any idea that how to do this then plz tell me?

Comment: I have opened a div on the same page using #TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=300&amp;inlineId=ProjectPopUp this URL. HERE ProjectPopUp is my div id. but here i want to open the content of iframe on clicking the link.

Comment: Thanks i understood what you want to say. open the iframe in the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer [Basic jQuery question: How to change iframe src by clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473295/basic-jquery-question-how-to-change-iframe-src-by-clicking-a-link)

```
<a href="foo.html" target="myiframe">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.html" target="myiframe">Bar</a>
<a href="baz.html" target="myiframe">Baz</a>

<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```