# Change the link in iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery

following is the iframe code i want to know how can i change the src link when lets say i'll click on any button and it changes the link and shows result accordingly without page reload

Thanks,

```
<iframe name="reloader" id="reloader" width="500" height="400" src="http://www.google.com/"/>
```

Comment: thanks for marking possible duplicate the solution over there is simply perfect!!!

Comment: how can i show the text of loading.... in the iframe section until the content gets load???

Comment: op changed the question after answer -1 sorry

Comment: I rolled back to your original question. If you need an answer to a different question, please ask a new question instead of editing an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourBtn').on('click', function(){
   $('#reloader').attr('src', 'yourNewLink'); 
})
```

Comment: hey can we put the text in the section of iframe at middle as loading... Until the iframe gets load

Comment: You can add an element with position:absolute, over the iframe, and make it dissapear when the iframe is loaded.

Comment: u mean something like <span style="position:absolute;">loading..,</span> ???

Comment: well that didnot help loading is not appearing but thanks for the heads up!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect solution,  if you can use links in place of button:

[Basic jQuery question: How to change iframe src by clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473295/basic-jquery-question-how-to-change-iframe-src-by-clicking-a-link)

Comment: how can i show the text of loading.... in the iframe section until the content gets load???

Answer (score 0):

( in case you were overcomplicating )

```
         <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com" target="reloader">
            click here
         </a>


        <iframe name="reloader" 
             id="reloader" width="500" 
             height="400" 
             src="http://www.google.com/"/>
```

without jquery ( being seo friendly and degrades well )

```
         <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com" class="mybutton" target="reloader">
            click here
         </a>


        <iframe name="reloader" 
             id="reloader" width="500" 
             height="400" 
             src="http://www.google.com/"/>



       <script type="text/javascript">

           $(".mybutton").click(function(e) {

              /* stop the link */
              e.preventDefault();

           /* get the url from the link */
           var url = $(this).attr("href");

          /* do something with it */
           $("#reloader").attr("src",url);

           });

       </script>
```

Comment: how can i show the text of loading.... in the iframe section until the content gets load???

Comment: different question and looks like you have changed this op to the new question also -1, sorry