# Display iframe content according to link

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `iframe` in my page and I want to display the content according to the link (anchor tag) selected.  I would like to achieve this using javascript.

My doubts are:

1. How to retrieve which anchor tag is selected.
2. If I call javascript from onclick() function in anchor tag and don't add a href attribute, then the anchor tag (link) loses it hyperlink property. So how can I add a href attribute in this case

Comment: From the question it looks like that you want [javascript - Directly link to page with specific content loaded in iframe - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946851/directly-link-to-page-with-specific-content-loaded-in-iframe) ; however you accepted the other answer which implies that the question is [javascript - Change iframe src by clicking a link - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473295/change-iframe-src-by-clicking-a-link) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your iframe a `name` attribute, IE:

```
<iframe src="startpage.html" name="content"></iframe>
```

Then when you create your links, set the `target` attribute to the same value. IE:

```
<a href="nextpage.html" target="content">Next Page</a>
```

Comment: And voila! Without the use of JS too.