# Directly link to page with specific content loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I have a front page with an iframe that loads different content. I want a url that will take users to the front page with pageA loaded in the iframe or another url with pageb loaded. How do I do this?

Is there a simple html solution I'm missing or is this a jquery thing?

Comment: Any help? Is this just not a thing that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query parameter to specify the page you want the iframe to load.

www.example.com/my/link/page.html?iframePage=website_a

Then you can use Javascript to check the parameter, and specify which page the iframe loads.

Here's an example [jsbin.](https://jsbin.com/hawinadevi/1/edit?html,js,output)

https://output.jsbin.com/hawinadevi/1?iframePage=website_a Loads Bing

Change the value of `website_a` to make the iframe load Bandcamp instead.