# How can I create a link to page and load specific content in iframe on that page

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

On our website we have a page that pulls content from another location in to an iFrame. I would like to know how I can create a link to the parent page and have a specific page load in the iFrame.

So, I'd like to create a link to http://xxx.xxx.com/page and have the iFrame on that page load http://yyy.xxx.com/anotherpage

Comment: You cannot control the contents of an Iframe that is from another domain due to the Same Origin Policy. This is by design in order to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: Well the content is coming from our domain. Just a different server. I'll edit my example to avoid further confusion.

Comment: iframes are read-only, in order to be able to edit them you must open up the actual file the iframe is rendering and edit it directly.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks

Comment: I've not tried this, but perhaps some javascript on the parent page, coupled with a query parameter in the link, would work? See [link here](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/html-xhtml-xml/31814-external-link-iframe.html)

Answer (score 5):

You should give your iframe element a name attribute and then target that name in your anchor tag.

Like so:

```
<iframe src="iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>

<a href="http://www.urltowebsite.com" target="iframe_a">My link</a>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sfpja/)

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for more info.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think the name attribute is what I'm looking for. But I want to post a link to http://wfcstaffing.com/contract-jobs/ and on that page I want a specific page to show in the iframe. So if I am posting a link on say twitter to this specific job http://temp.workforcecarolina.com/JobBoard/JobDetails.aspx?__appid__=3006ca37-9c5e-4130-8974-86815bd9846d&__job__=17331

I want it to show in the iFrame on http://wfcstaffing.com/contract-jobs/

I want this because there is no way to get back to any of the other content from that job posting.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Then it's another story as some other commenters have pointed out.

Comment: Yes, looks like the question is more like a duplicate of [javascript - Directly link to page with specific content loaded in iframe - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946851/directly-link-to-page-with-specific-content-loaded-in-iframe) ;; while this is an answer to [javascript - Change iframe src by clicking a link - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473295/change-iframe-src-by-clicking-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

you'd have to add an iframe to http://xxx.xxx.com/page like this:

```
<iframe src="http://xxx.yyy.com/anotherpage"></iframe>
```

Comment: I have that... works fine... my question is when I post a link to xxx.xxx.com I want the iframe on that page to load specific content.

We are posting jobs from an internal job board on an iis server to our external website. I want to be able to post links to the parent page with specific results in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking:

Forms like https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp this should give something like "index.php?getresult=someinput" right?

so if you link to your page like:

xxx.xxx.com/index.php?showpage=myrequestedpage

and

xxx.xxx.com/index.php

index.php contains

```html
<?php
   //pseudo-code to:
   //function getiframe(){
     //$showpage = $_GET (this should get "myrequestedpage") .".php";
     //if no ?showpage available then $showpage = "defaultpage.php"
   //}
   // return $showpage;
?>
<iframe src="http://xxx.yyy.com/<?php getiframe(); ?>"></iframe>
```

I was having this in mind while I started searching for easyer/better solutions to the question Original Poster had, but I think this ... should ... work right?

ps. sorry for gravedigging(just noticed after writing the pseudocode), but i have the same question and thisone popped up on top in google, so hoping this would bring my thoughtprocess to a finished product as well and maybe someone has better idea's years later.

edit:
tested this to be working indeed. xxx.xxx.com/index.php?pagina=specificpage

```html
<?php
    if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) {
        $pagina = "home.php";
    }else{
        $pagina = $_GET['pagina'].".php";
    }
?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $pagina; ?>" style="border:none;" title="websites" height="100%" width="100%" name="target_frame"></iframe>
```