# Links in embedded html

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

I have some HTML code I'm trying to embed into a site.
The code is an iframe that is supposed to have a bunch of links in it, but when I click the links, they just load the page inside the iframe block.

[image: before click]
[image: after click]

Here is the code:

base.html

```
<head height="200" width="300">
    Text
</head>
<div>
<body>
    <iframe height="200" width="300" src="test.html"></iframe>
</body>
</div>
```

test.html

```
<head>
    <a href="file:///Users/Jean/base.html">Link</a>
</head>
```

Is there a way for me to tell the link NOT to load inside the frame?

I already know of a workaround which is to add "target="_blank"" to the link so it opens in a new tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a link to page and load specific content in iframe on that page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618314/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-page-and-load-specific-content-in-iframe-on-that-page)

Comment: try `target="_parent"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `target` attribute as shown below

```
<a href="file:///Users/Jean/base.html" target="_parent">Link</a>
```

the tag `_parent` will target the iframe's immediate parent window. 
the tag `_top` will target the top window.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `target="_top"` this should target the parent URL instead of the iframe URL

```
<head>
    <a target="_top" href="file:///Users/Jean/base.html">Link</a>
</head>
```