# HTML how to target a link in a iframe to another iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Working Code

assuming you have a page with two different iframe where the first menu and the second container of the selected page.

how can I at the click of a link in the menu frame display the selected page iframe container?

In menu page i have this

```
...
 </li>
         <li class="title"><a href='javascript:parent.document.getElementById("frame").src = "pages/setting.php"'><?php echo $lang['MENU_IMPOSTAZIONI']; ?></a>
         <img src="images/bullet_arrow_down.png" /></li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
...
```

in index this:

```
...
<iframe id="menufrm" src="menu.php" width="250px" height="700px" frameborder="none"></iframe>
<iframe name="frame" src="" width="99%" height="99%" frameborder="none"></iframe>
 ...
```

But with this, when i click in the button in menu the page is displayed correctly in container, but menu.php disappears and in its place appears a string with relative path of the document displayed in iframe.

how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change iframe src by clicking a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473295/change-iframe-src-by-clicking-a-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<iframe src="frame1.html" name="myFrame">
<a href="frame2.html" target="myFrame">
```

Comment: that's work if you're clicking a link in the main page and refer to an iframe, but, when you click a link into an iframe and refer to another iframe it doesn't work!

Comment: You should use "name" instead of "id" on the iframe, then it should work from another iframe.

Answer (score 1):

'The best solution is probably to use a target on your `<a>` element.
Alternatively you can use javascript this way:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="parent.document.getElementById('frame').src = 'pages/setting.php'">...
```

Comment: i've tried but, seems don't work, when i click nothing happened. i didn't understand where is the error...

Comment: I corrected the quotes on my example. This should work, as long as all pages are on the same domain. The target example is still a better one, I added a comment on that answer.

Comment: doesn't work, open the setting.php page in same frame of the menu leaving target iframe blank