# Update iFrame src a click of a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code below, and I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks the text of a video streaming website they wish to watch the video from, it will update inside of the iframe.

```
<iframe src="<!-- Desired URL from a href should be here -->" height="240" width="100%">

<ul class="video-links">
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">YouTube</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">Vimeo</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">DailyMotion</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">Veoh</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">Crackle</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I go about doing this in a way that can scale just from adding more `<li>` tags into our `video-links` `ul` class?

Comment: How do you catch an event?  How do you select an elemet such as an iframe?  How do you change an attribute?  There is no code in your question to show which of these issues you are having problems solving

Comment: @Taplar I am asking how to make my `a href` the `src` value of the iFrame on click, what don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand what your particular issue is.  Without saying what your issue is, this reads as a coding request.  You've stated what you want.  You have not stated what problem you have doing it yourself.

Comment: @Taplar this is for sure not a "coding request" he's asking how to update an element on click, what makes his issue different than the hundreds of other questions that are exactly this same thing?

Comment: @Placeholder other questions show effort in solving the problem.  This question does not.  That is the mark of a coding request.

Comment: this is someone asking for someone to do their homework. This is a coding request. Flagged.

Comment: We really don't know if this is homework or not, but I stand by that this question did not state what their problem is.  Ref. [ask].  "In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the **problem** you're trying to solve, and **any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself**. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."  This question does not state a problem.  It states what the user wants.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473295/change-iframe-src-by-clicking-a-link

Answer (score 1):

The fully working code:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="" height="240" width="100%"></iframe>

<ul class="video-links">
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com" onclick="return changeSrc(this)">YouTube</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com" onclick="return changeSrc(this)">Vimeo</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com" onclick="return changeSrc(this)">DailyMotion</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com" onclick="return changeSrc(this)">Veoh</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com" onclick="return changeSrc(this)">Crackle</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function changeSrc(obj)
{
    document.getElementById("myiframe").src = obj.href;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Now comes the explanation of the few edits I made to your code:

- iframe tags must be closed, otherwise page will not appear correctly.
- You must use JavaScript to modify the page dynamically.
- You can write JavaScript functions in the `script` tag.
- `onclick` is a callback, which is called when the user clicks on something in the page. We call the `changeSrc` function, passing `this` as parameter, because we want to pass the object which we are clicking.
- We must `return false`, otherwise page will follow the link in the `href` attribute. There are alternatives to this, but I'm trying to be simple with my solution.
- We assign an `id` to your `iframe` and get it to manage its properties, like `src`, so it can be set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some syntactical sugar added on to FonzTech's answer.

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="" height="240" width="100%"></iframe>

<ul class="video-links">
   <li data-link="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">YouTube</li>
   <li data-link="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">Vimeo</li>
   <li data-link="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">DailyMotion</li>
   <li data-link="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">Veoh</li>
   <li data-link="https://our-unique-url-for-this-title.com">Crackle</li>
</ul>

<script>
    // Get a NodeList of all li elements inside .video-links
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.video-links li')

    // Loop through each item in the NodeList
    elements.forEach((el) => {
        // Add a click event to each item
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Scrape the data-link attribute from the current li element
            let link = el.attributes['data-link'].value;

            // Set the iframe's src attribute
            document.getElementById("myiframe").src = link;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Instead of using an anchor tag's href attribute for storing data, I suggest using custom data attributes as that is what they are made for. In addition to that you don't have to keep the browser from following the link.

This solution also doesn't use inline JS which some consider to be a "bad" or "messy" practice.