# Is Lazyload retained when loading different webpage in iframe by clicking <a> tag in same page?

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, lazy-loading, href, target

I saw this solution on another thread to load a different webpage in an iframe on the same page when clicking the  tag by targeting the name of the iframe, without needing to use javascript.

```
<a href="foo.html" target="myiframe">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.html" target="myiframe">Bar</a>
<a href="baz.html" target="myiframe">Baz</a>

<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1473330/8915233

But will the iframe retain the lazyload and other attributes on each click? For example:

```
<iframe name="myiframe" loading="lazy" allow="accelerometer; gyroscope;"></iframe>
```

Can I see somewhere in Chrome DevTools whether or not lazyload is currently happening?

And how can I get the brwoser to jump to the iframe at the middle of the page if the clicked link was at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Lazy load will work if it is offscreen.
And if the `iframe`  is onscreen then you will not be able to notice the lazy loading.